# Why is the default: () => [], and not just []?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

This question is related to ***JS and Vue2 framework***.
I would like to understand what a specific line of code means,  `default: () => [],`. Why is the empty array set through the arrow function, and not just []?

```
export default {
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
};
```

**Broader context:**
I am trying to figure out the logic behind a vue autocomplete app.
Here is the full codepen:
https://codepen.io/alligatorio/pen/mXRGLg

Thanks!

Comment: An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) returning an empty array. Same as `function() { return []; }`.

Comment: Thanks Tushar! This is exactly what I was looking for. Guess I need to read a bit more about the arrow functions. I though I understand them.